# Iterating through buffer design issue

Tags: c, errno

I'm working on a event driven application and would like to provide a high level API to the system's low level interface. I'm currently in doubt about how to propagate `errno` down the call stack. Here is my current API

```
typedef struct watcher_t watcher_t;

typedef struct event_iterator_t event_iterator_t;

event_iterator_t *poll_events(watcher_t *watcher, 
                              int poll_timeout_millis, 
                              void *buffer);

const char* take_event_path(void *event_buffer, 
                            event_iterator_t *iterator);
```

The problem is the caller of poll events currently has no other choice except using `errno`. I mean

```
#include <errno.h>

void *buf = //...
watcher_t *watcher_ptr = //...
event_iterator_t * iterator_ptr = poll_events(watcher_ptr, 1000, buf);
if(iterator_ptr == NULL){
   perror("Error while getting iterator");
}
```

I'm not sure if such approach commonly used. Is there any benefits of declaring the result type as `int` and an `event_iterator_t **` as out parameter.

```
int poll_events(watcher_t *watcher, 
               int poll_timeout_millis, 
               void *buffer,
               event_iterator_t **out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if such approach commonly used. Is there any benefits of declaring the result type as int and an event_iterator_t ** as out parameter.

Both approaches are common. But when the function returns an `int` result code, it it easier to be thread-safe and the API is easier to document.

I advise using the following approach:

- return an int as result code
- pass a context handler as first parameter, that would contain the watchers, the iterator, etc.

Example:

```
int api_init_context(api_context_t *ctx);
int api_add_watcher(api_context_t *ctx, watcher_t *watcher);
int api_poll_events(api_context_t *ctx, int poll_timeout_millis, void *buffer);
int api_take_event_path(api_context_t *ctx, void *event_buffer);
```

Comment: But the `errno` is thread local anyway. So what would cause some complication?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to propagate the error you:
1. Set the return type to be the error/0. Then do as it is listed in your second scenario.
2. If setting errno is enough for you you may stick on returning NULL if things get grim while setting errno appropriately.

The only thing you should stick to is to do it the same way through the API and make it possible to indicate an error *always* and do it the same way.